# How to get Sharepoint 2013 variation URL?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, csom

I want to create a toggle button for variations, so that when I am on the `en` or `fr` page, and I click the button it takes me to the other page. But I can't just change the `en` to `fr`, for example, because someone can rename the page. So I need to write code that can get the correct URL. I found this article

http://rwcchen.blogspot.ca/2015/02/sharepoint-2013-get-variation-url-using.html

which says it can do it using the relationships list, but I am having trouble running the script. It always fails with error `Cannot complete this action. Please try again.`. I know the list exists because if I visit

```
http://my-page/Relationships%20List/AllItems.aspx
```

Then I can see the list there with items. This is my code, does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(VariationHandler, "sp.js"); 
});

function VariationHandler() {

    Type.registerNamespace('spapp');

    var context;
    spapp.url = "http://my-page/";
    spapp.language;
    spapp.languageHome;
    spapp.curPageUrl;
    spapp.relationshipList;
    spapp.relationshipItems;

    context = new SP.ClientContext(spapp.url);

    spapp.curPageUrl = _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath;
    spapp.language = _spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName;

    spapp.relationshipList = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Relationships List");

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(
        '' + spapp.curPageUrl + '');
    spapp.relationshipItems = spapp.relationshipList.getItems(camlQuery);

    context.load(spapp.relationshipItems);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        onGetGroupId,
        onQueryFailed
    );
}




function onGetGroupId(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = spapp.relationshipItems.getEnumerator();

    spapp.languageHome = "/fr";
    if (spapp.language.toLowerCase().indexOf("fr-") > -1) {
        spapp.languageHome = "/en";
    }

    if (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var groupId = oListItem.get_item('GroupGuid');

        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();


        camlQuery.set_viewXml('' + groupId + '' + spapp.languageHome + 'false');
        spapp.relationshipItems = spapp.relationshipList.getItems(camlQuery);
        context.load(spapp.relationshipItems);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, onGetVariationUrl),
            Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed)
        );
    } else {
        document.location = spapp.languageHome;
    }
}

function onGetVariationUrl(sender, args) {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = spapp.relationshipItems.getEnumerator();

    if (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var objectID = oListItem.get_item('ObjectID');

        var a = objectID.get_url(); //redirect to the variation.
    } else {
        var a = spapp.languageHome;
    }

    console.log(a);
    //document.location = a;
}

function onQueryFailed (sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() +
        '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I found the two CAML queries from the article

```
'<view><query><where><contains><fieldref objectid="" name="\"><value type="\">'+spapp.curPageUrl+'</value></fieldref></contains></where></query></view>'

'<view><query><where><and><and><contains><fieldref name="\\" groupguid=""><value type="\\" guid="">'+groupId+'</value></fieldref></contains><contains><fieldref objectid="" name="\\"><value type="\\">'+spapp.languageHome+'</value></fieldref></contains></and><eq><fieldref deleted="" name="\\"><value boolean="" type="\\">false</value></fieldref></eq></and></where></query></view>'
```

But they are messed up. Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

**EDIT 2**

I changed it to this now

```
'<view>
    <query>
        <where>
            <contains>
                <fieldref name="ObjectID" />
                <value type="Hyperlink or Picture">' + spapp.curPageUrl + '</value>
            </contains>
        </where>
    </query>
</view>'

'<view>
    <query>
        <where>
            <and>
                <and>
                    <contains>
                        <fieldref Name="GroupGuid" />
                        <value type="guid">' + groupId + '</value>
                    </contains>
                    <contains>
                        <fieldref name="ObjectID" />
                        <value type="Hyperlink or Picture">'+spapp.languageHome+'</value>
                    </contains>
                </and>
                <eq>
                    <fieldref name="Deleted" />
                    <value type="boolean">false</value>
                </eq>
            </and>
        </where>
    </query>
</view>'
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems the caml query tags were hidden on that page. Need to inspect the code to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simply take a look to the **getPeerUrl()** method in the SP.Publishing.Variations namespace: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj954403.aspx

Try this

```
jQuery.getScript("_layouts/15/sp.publishing.js",null)
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var peerUrl = SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl(clientContext, "/fr/Pages/MyPage.aspx","en")

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    alert(peerUrl.get_value())}
);
```

Comment: How do I use this, I can't find any example code.

Comment: I tried the new code, but I get a SP.Result object and if I call `.get_value()` on it, I get `0` back...

Comment: Is it the relative URL of the current aspx page you passed? According to your code, currently you pass the root web URL which is wrong. You can try with an hardcoded value like my example on any page to be sure. Check if the the label title is correct too.

Comment: Solution is here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148078/how-to-use-the-csom-sp-publishing-variations-getpeerurl-method#148080