# How to use the CSOM SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl method?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, variations

In this code, I am trying to get the corressponding french URL variation. I am using this CSOM api

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj954403.aspx

But I can't figure out how to use it. Does anyone know?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(VariationHandler, "sp.js"); 


    function VariationHandler() {
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var site = ctx.get_site();
        var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();
        var webProperties = rootWeb.get_allProperties();

        ctx.load(site);
        ctx.load(rootWeb);
        ctx.load(webProperties);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(

            function() {
                var varLabelsListId = webProperties.get_item('_VarLabelsListId');

                var labelsList = rootWeb.get_lists().getById(varLabelsListId);
                var labelItems = labelsList.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());

                ctx.load(labelItems);
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(

                    function() {

                        var object = new SP.Publishing.Variations();
                        var qq = object.getPeerUrl(ctx);
                        alert(qq);



                    },
                    function() {
                    }
                );
            },
            function() {
            }
        );

    }
</script>
```

---

NEW

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var site = ctx.get_site();
var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();
var webProperties = rootWeb.get_allProperties();

ctx.load(site);
ctx.load(rootWeb);
ctx.load(webProperties);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(

    function() {
        var varLabelsListId = webProperties.get_item('_VarLabelsListId');

        var labelsList = rootWeb.get_lists().getById(varLabelsListId);
        var labelItems = labelsList.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());

        ctx.load(labelItems);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(

            function() {
                var url = rootWeb.get_serverRelativeUrl();
                var object = new SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl(url, "en-US");



            },
            function() {
            }
        );
    },
    function() {
    }
);
```

---

**NEW AGAIN**

```
function VariationHandler2() {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var site = ctx.get_site();
    var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();
    var webProperties = rootWeb.get_allProperties();

    ctx.load(site);
    ctx.load(rootWeb);
    ctx.load(webProperties);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(

        function() {
            var varLabelsListId = webProperties.get_item('_VarLabelsListId');

            var labelsList = rootWeb.get_lists().getById(varLabelsListId);
            var labelItems = labelsList.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());

            ctx.load(labelItems);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                function() {
                    var url = rootWeb.get_serverRelativeUrl();
                    var object = SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl(ctx, url, "en");
                    alert(object.get_value());
                },
                function() {
                }
            );
        },
        function() {
        }
    );  
}
```

---

**NEW NEW NEW**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(VariationHandler, "sp.js"); 
});

function VariationHandler() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(VariationHandler2, "SP.publishing.js"); 
}

function VariationHandler2() {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var site = ctx.get_site();
    var rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();
    var webProperties = rootWeb.get_allProperties();

    ctx.load(site);
    ctx.load(rootWeb);
    ctx.load(webProperties);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(

        function() {
            var varLabelsListId = webProperties.get_item('_VarLabelsListId');

            var labelsList = rootWeb.get_lists().getById(varLabelsListId);
            var labelItems = labelsList.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());

            ctx.load(labelItems);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(

                function() {
                    var url = rootWeb.get_serverRelativeUrl();


                    var object = SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl(ctx, "/en/Pages/default.aspx", "fr");

                    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                        function() {
                            console.log(object.get_value());
                            alert(object);
                            alert(object.get_value());
                            alert(JSON.stringify(object));
                        }, function() {
                        }
                    );
                },
                function() {
                }
            );
        },
        function() {
        }
    );  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter count for getPeerUrl() is wrong. According to the documentation (even if it is ambiguous) you must pass the current URL (server relative) and variation label too.

Check the JS function signature SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl, it takes 3 parameters.

Try this

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(VariationHandler2, "SP.publishing.js"); 

    function VariationHandler2() {
        var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var object = SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl(ctx, "/en/Pages/default.aspx", "fr");
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(

            function() {
                alert(object.get_value());
            }
        );  
    }
```

Your problem is that you call the getPeerUrl method in the executeQueryAsync function. You must execute it before.

Comment: I added my new code above, but it says `.Variations` result is undefined. I checked developer tools, and Sp.Publishing does not contain a value for key `Variations`.

Comment: Is the script SP.publishing.js correctly loaded?

Comment: ok so I didnt do that, but now I did, and I got the object from getPeerUrl(), but now how do I extract the url from it? I put my new code above.

Comment: the new code alerts `0`.

Comment: I tried the new code, but I get a SP.Result object and if I call `.get_value()` on it, I get `0` back...

Comment: Is it the relative URL of the current aspx page you passed? According to your code, currently you pass the root web URL which is wrong. You can try with an hardcoded value like my example on any page to be sure. Check if the the label title is correct too.

Comment: I tried this `var object = SP.Publishing.Variations.getPeerUrl(ctx, "/en/Pages/default.aspx", "fr");` but it gave `0` still...

Comment: Are you sure the variation label title is "fr" and not "fr-FR"?

Comment: I checked my `Variation Labels ` settings page, and there is two labels, whose label and display name are `en` and `fr` respectively for each.

Comment: Ok it's really weird. I'm testing with a basic example and everything is fine. Can you post your code?

Comment: ok I added it on top.

Comment: I put the executeQueryAsync and got an error message now `---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
Request failed. Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Parameter name: currentUrl
undefined
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
`

Comment: Try the new code, you must call the getPeerUrl method out of the executeQueryAsync  method

Comment: Ok I figured it out. I had a managed path `/sites/mysite` so my actual server relative path is  `/sites/mysite/en/Pages/default.aspx`. Thanks for help.

Comment: Your welcome! Happy variations ;)

Comment: Actually one more thing pls, how can I dynamically get the server relative path? The one that gives me `/sites/mysite/en/Pages/default.aspx`.

Comment: Maybe your can try `window.location.pathname`